# Certificate Authority - RADIUS/WPA

Tags: radius, wpa

We have a problem with our Certificate Authority, it deletes its own Computer Certificate day-by-day. I implement a WPA wireless security via RADIUS standard with using that computer. So everyday I have to renew computer certificate. When I check Event viewer, three logs are shown as :

> Source : IAS   Event ID : 3
>
> Access request for user User1 was
>   discarded.  Fully-Qualified-User-Name
>   = domain.com/Users/User1  NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.0.66 
>   NAS-Identifier = Wireless 
>   Called-Station-Identifier =
>   001d.45d3.4190 
>   Calling-Station-Identifier =
>   0023.df15.1483  Client-Friendly-Name = Wireless  Client-IP-Address =
>   192.168.0.66  NAS-Port-Type = Wireless - IEEE 802.11  NAS-Port = 5113  Proxy-Policy-Name = Use Windows
>   authentication for all users 
>   Authentication-Provider = Windows
>   Authentication-Server = 
>   Reason-Code = 23  Reason = Unexpected
>   error. Possible error in server or
>   client configuration.
>
> Source : IAS   Event ID : 20168
>
> Could not retrieve the Remote Access
>   Server's certificate due to the 
>   following error: Cannot find object or
>   property.
>
> Source : IAS   Event ID : 20168
>
> Because no certificate has been
>   configured for clients dialing in with
>   EAP-TLS, a default certificate is
>   being sent to user Domain\User1.
>   Please go to the user's Remote Access
>   Policy and configure the Extensible
>   Authentication Protocol (EAP).

What could cause the problem?

Comment: This logs are all about connection problem, here is logs I found in Applications tab, I hope they will be more helpful to find a solution about my problem 

Event ID : 1085

The Group Policy client-side extension IP Security failed to execute. Please look for any errors reported earlier by that extension.

Event ID : 1091

The Group Policy client-side extension IP Security failed to log RSOP (Resultant Set of Policy) data. Please look for any errors reported earlier by that extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the real solution.

> To describle the process of
>   duplicating the template and issuing
>   the certificate more clearly, I would
>   like to provide a more precise action
>   plan as following.
>
> 1. On CA, create a duplicate of the "RAS and IAS Server certificate
>      template". Type RAS and IAS Server
>      Authentication into the Template
>      display name field on the General tab
>      of the new template's properties.
> 2. On the Extensions tab, ensure that the application policies only include
>      Server Authentication (OID
>      1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1).
> 3. Also on the  Extensions tab, edit the Issuance policies and add the
>      Medium Assurance policy.
> 4. On the Subject Name tab, select Build from this Active Directory
>      information. Also, ensure that Subject
>      name format is set to Common name and
>      that only DNS anme is selected under
>      include this information in subject
>      alternative name.
> 5. On the Request Handing tab, click the CSPs button, ensure that Request
>      must use one of the following CSPs is
>      selected, and that only the Microsoft
>      RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider is
>      selected.
> 6. On the Security tab, add the AutoEnroll RAS and IAS Server
>      Authentication Certificate security
>      group with Read, Enroll, and
>      Autoenroll permissions.
> 7. Add certificate templates to the CA.
> 8. From the Certification Authority MMC snap-in, right-click the
>      Certificate Templates folder, select
>      New and then Certificate Template to
>      Issue. Selectthe following
>      certificates, and then click OK.
>
> "RAS and IAS Server Authentication"
>
> 9. Log on to the IAS server as a member of the local Administrators
>      group.
> 10. Open the MMC, and then add the Certificates snap-in. When prompted,
>       select the Computer account option,
>       and then select Local Computer.
> 11. Select Certificates (Local Computer) from the console tree,
>       select All Tasks from the Action menu,
>       and then click Automatically Enroll
>       Certificates

Answer (score 1):

It works. Any argument ?

> most likely the certificate is
>   deleted by some application. Sometimes
>   the certificate is not deleted, but
>   rather archived.  To verify, please
>   run certmgr.msc and open the
>   certificate snap-in. Then click
>   Certificates->View->Options and select
>   Archive Certificates. the certificates
>   show up again.
>
> It could be the Live Sync program that
>   deletes/archive the certificate. To
>   verify, please try not to use the
>   program on the machine and monitor if
>   the certificate gets deleted/archived.
>   I also found that the software
>   FolderShare can also cause this kind
>   of problem. If you have this software
>   installed, please remove or disabled
>   this software. Thank you.
>
> To troubleshot it, I recommend we
>   operate a clean boot the problematic
>   machine and check it again.
>
> To perform a clean boot, please follow
>   these steps.
>
> 1. Type MSCONFIG to open system configuration console.
> 2. Go to Services tab, click the option to hide all Microsoft
>      Services and then click the Disable
>      All button.
> 3. Go to Startup tab, click the Disable All button.
> 4. Restart the computer.

Comment: Last update, I didn't work for us . Is there anyone who any another idea ?